# How to use callable targets with dataclass arguments in Hydra?

Tags: fb-hydra, omegaconf

Is it possible to define a target using Structured Configs to avoid redefining all the parameters?

```py
def good(config: Config):
    pass

def bad(param1, param2):
    pass

@dataclass
class Config:
    param1
    param2
    _target_: Any = good
    # _target_: Any = bad
    # _target_: str = 'Config.also_good'

    def also_good(self):
        pass
```

What type annotation should I use for `_target_` in case of a class, function, or method? When I used Any I got

```
omegaconf.errors.UnsupportedValueType: Value 'function' is not a supported primitive type
    full_key: _target_
```

Comment: Hi Emre, normally the `_target_` has type `str`, e.g. `_target_: str = "__main__.good"` or `_target_: str = "my_module.bad"`. The value of `_target_` should be the dotpath used to look up the callable that you are targeting. See the `PostGreSQLConfig` example on Hydra's [Structured Configs example](https://hydra.cc/docs/advanced/instantiate_objects/structured_config/) webpage.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by asking "Is it possible to define a target using Structured Configs to avoid redefining all the parameters?" Could you please clarify what you mean by "avoid redefining the parameters?" If you are talking about avoiding duplication of "param1" in different places (e.g. in the function signature and in the dataclass body), see https://github.com/facebookresearch/hydra/issues/1936.

Comment: I mean using a target with one dataclass parameter, rather than a bunch of primitive parameters for each field of the dataclass. I saw that issue but did not see how hydra-zen solves the problem. Feel free to post an answer showing how it does.

Comment: I am still confused about what you are trying to achieve. What is the relationship between the good / bad / also_good functions in your example? Have you tried running a hydra app and, if so, are you getting an error message? More details in your question would be helpful.

Comment: The good ones accept dataclasses (`also_good` through `self`), and bad one does not. When I try to run it clearly indicates it is looking for the primitive parameters because the error messages say they are missing, and names them. My dataclasses have many fields, and it is unwieldy to keep the signatures in sync. Also, the documentation says target could be callable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `_target_` type should be `str`.
Here is an example using the [`instantiate` API](https://hydra.cc/docs/advanced/instantiate_objects/overview/) with a structured config:

```py
# example.py
from dataclasses import dataclass

from hydra.utils import instantiate


def trgt(arg1: int, arg2: float):
    print(f"trgt function: got {arg1}, {arg2}")
    return "foobar"


@dataclass
class Config:
    _target_: str = "__main__.trgt"  # dotpath describing location of callable
    arg1: int = 123
    arg2: float = 10.1


val = instantiate(Config)
print(f"Returned value was {val}.")
```

Running the script:

```
$ python example.py
trgt function: got 123, 10.1
Returned value was foobar.
```

Notes:

- The `_target_` field must be a string describing the "dotpath" used to look up a callable (`__main__.trgt` in the example above). Other typical dotpaths would be e.g. `my_module.my_function`, `builtins.range` `numpy.random.randn`, etc. The `instantiate` function uses this dotpath to find the callable object that will be instantiated (the `trgt` function, in this example).
- The fields of the structured config (except for the `_target_` field and other special reserved fields such as `_recursive_`, `_convert_` and `_args_`) will be passed as *keyword arguments* to the looked-up callable. In this example, the function `trgt` is called with keyword arguments `arg1=123` and `arg2=10.1`. This is equivalent to the python code `trgt(arg1=123, arg2=10.1)`.
- If you define a structured config (using `@dataclass` or `@attr.s`), you can specify a default value for each field. For example, the default value for field `arg1` above is `123`. Calling `instantiate(config)` will result in an exception if `config` has any fields whose values are missing. Typically, a structured config's missing values will be filled in during Hydra's config composition process.

References:

- [OmegaConf docs on structured configs](https://omegaconf.readthedocs.io/en/2.1_branch/structured_config.html)
- [Hydra examples using `_target_` with structured configs](https://hydra.cc/docs/advanced/instantiate_objects/structured_config/)